# Migrating Database Causes "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_Membership_GetPasswordWithFormat'"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, vevocart

I am migrating my server from one box to another, both have Microsoft SQL Server 2014 running Plesk.

After migrating to the new box, I receive the error:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_Membership_GetPasswordWithFormat'.]
```

Here is a bit longer stack trace.

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_Membership_GetPasswordWithFormat'.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1787814
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5341674
```

1. I created a backup of the db on the old system.
2. I created a new db on the new box
3. I restored the db

I did see, [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165908/could-not-find-stored-procedure-dbo-aspnet-checkschemaversion) and [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987079/localhost-cannot-find-stored-procedure-dbo-aspnet-checkschemaversion), which talks not being able to find stored procedure, 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'. Actually, I had that problem too. I ran:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S <servername> -U <user> -P <password -R all -d <dbname>
aspnet_regsql.exe -S <servername> -U <user> -P <password -A all -d <dbname>
```

I ran that to remove everything and then add everything back. That cured that particular problem, however I then ran into my current problem.

Login is fine using SSMS. This problem occurs, when I go to the website and attempt to log in. Pressing the submit button throws the error.

I do know that this stored procedure is part of ASP.Net v4.0 (the site uses v4.0). The backup/restore was full to full. I did a manual check and all looks fine. I doubt that permissions are an issue and I added all features, so what is left?

I did see [this article](http://forums.asp.net/t/1679744.aspx?Error%20Could%20not%20find%20stored%20procedure%20dbo%20aspnet_Membership_GetPasswordWithFormat%20) on a similar issue. The answer stated that it looks like a required ALTER command, however the person responding failed to elaborate what that ALTER statement should be. I would concur that the answer involves that.

Articles Possible of Interest
[VevoCart Forum - Collation](http://forum.vevocart.com/topic1937-defaultaspxproductlist-does-not-display.aspx)

**NOTE**:

I receive this error trying to log into my VevoCart online shopping cart system/site. Everything was fine until I migrated servers.

I was debugging through VS logging in as a customer and saw the complaint as "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles_IsUserInRole'."". I just did a quick search and that is a Microsoft .Net function. That matches the same type of issue than in the Admin login, namely not being able to access the ASP.Net stored procedure. I am surprised that the command line above did not work. I would think that would be the resolution to the problem.

Comment: The article you listed there suggests the database Collation is not set correctly.  Which Collation set are you trying to use?

Comment: If a collation. I am merely listing references that I found, much like I did in my mysql-connector thread. Listing my research here helps me keep my thoughts organized. That is what led me to eventually drilling down to the solution with the machine.config file. I added a note that this error happens when I try to log into my VevoCart shopping cart.

Comment: maybe you misunderstand.  What I am suggesting is that this is likely a problem with the SQL Collation settings.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281995.aspx.  Knowing which language set you are using for Database Collation is necessary to track down the root issue.

Comment: I just added a reference an article that I found on the VevoCart forums mentioning collation. To answer your question, no clue. I installed SQL Server and did the migration. I have to check the settings.

Comment: The database collation is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP!_Cl_AS", however I have no idea where the collation setting is on IIS. Microsoft states that the database collation that I have should be the correct setting.

Comment: Did you check to see if the stored procedure exists?  Can you "modify" both but don't save any updates?